# Python append removes elements from list

Tags: python

I have a function that appends a list to a list, but for some reason certain elements from that list get cleared...

Here is the function

```
def calculate_path(current_location, furthest):
    path = []
    directions = [[0, -1], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, -1]]
    i = 0
    for direction in furthest:  # n e s w
        temp_location = copy.deepcopy(current_location)
        while temp_location != direction:
            temp_location[directions[i][0]] += directions[i][1]
            path.append(temp_location)
            print(path)
        i += 1
    return path
```

So given an input of `current_location = [4, 4]`, `furthest = [[1, 4], [4, 7], [5, 4], [4, 0]]` the program gives this output:

```
[[3, 4]]
[[2, 4], [2, 4]]
[[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]]
[[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [4, 5]]
[[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [4, 6], [4, 6]]
[[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [4, 7], [4, 7], [4, 7]]
[[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [4, 7], [4, 7], [4, 7], [5, 4]]
[[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [4, 7], [4, 7], [4, 7], [5, 4], [4, 3]]
[[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [4, 7], [4, 7], [4, 7], [5, 4], [4, 2], [4, 2]]
[[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [4, 7], [4, 7], [4, 7], [5, 4], [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1]]
[[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [4, 7], [4, 7], [4, 7], [5, 4], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0]]
```

As you can see, it adds `[3, 4]` but then removes it? And the same for others? I realy can't work out why this might be happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inside the `while` loop you basically only work with the variable `temp_location` to append to the list `path`. For all iterations in that loop every element you append refers to the very same object.

So having 3 iterations in the `while` loop during one iteration of the outer `for` loop, will result in 3 elements being appended to your list, but with each element referring to the very same object.

You can avoid this by appending a copy of `temp_location` to the list:

```
path.append(temp_location.copy())
```